# Составить новую строку из двух других подстрок

Tags: javascript

В общем, есть задача даны три строки и нужно вернуть строку которая как бы первая но состоит из 2 и 3. Если проще то вернуть строку из подстрок. Только например одна из должна быть в toUpperCase.

```
Example:

str1 = stopam

str2 = sam

str3 = top

return => StopAM
```

Я пытался сделать подобным перебором, но не понимаю как сделать так чтобы каждый шаг в цикле массива он делал полную проверку на наличие символов в str1. ТО есть каждую новую итерацию полностью проверял наличие похожих символов и в str2 и в str3 и если находит соответствие то пушит в масив с результатом.

```
var resMas = []

var mas1 = ["s","t","o", "p", "g", "a", "m", "e"],
    mas2 = ["s", "a", "m"],
    mas3 = ["t", "o", "p", "g", "e"]

function revString(mas1, mas2, mas3){
  for(let i = 0; i < mas1.length; i++){
    if (mas2.indexOf(mas1[i]) != -1){
      resMas.push(mas2[i])
      console.log(resMas)
    } else if (mas3.indexOf(mas1[i]) != -1){
      resMas.push(mas3[i])
      console.log(resMas)
    }
  }
  return resMas;
}

console.log(revString(mas1, mas2, mas3)) //StopgAMe
```

Помогите исправить код. Ну или решить, тут кому как хочется, буду благодарен.

Comment: Если это **учебное задание**, то дайте текст этого задания, если ваша личная задумка, то опишите какой результат нужно. Я трижды перечитал и никак понять не могу, что вы хотите..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ещё раз перечитал, всмотрелся в код.. И всё же ничего не понял..

---

> Я пытался сделать подобным перебором, но не понимаю как сделать так чтобы каждый шаг в цикле массива он делал полную проверку на наличие символов в str1

`.indexOf` и так, по сути, проходит весь массив, но он останавливается на первом совпадение.
По условиям, опять же, если буква нашлась в `mas2`, то поиска в `mas3` - не будет, а если не нашлось в `mas2`, то будет искать в `mas3`.
Ну и самое интересное - если нет в `mas2` и в `mas3`, то текущий шаг ничего не добавит в `resMas`.

---

Я переписал код чуть иначе, теперь это функция, в котором ваши `mas1-3` передаются параметрами.
Суть кода такая же как и у вас, но чуть "проще" работает.

Я ещё визуализировал цикл, выводя каждый шаг в `<body>`.
На третьем примере (`непонятно`) видно, как работает описанное в начале сообщения.

> По условиям, опять же, если буква нашлась в `mas2`, то поиска в `mas3` - не будет, а если не нашлось в `mas2`, то будет искать в `mas3`.
> Ну и самое интересное - если нет в `mas2` и в `mas3`, то текущий шаг ничего не добавит в `resMas`.

```js
let test = document.querySelector('#test'); // # ДЛЯ ТЕСТА

function revString(str1, str2, str3){
  str1 = str1.split('');
  str2 = str2.split('');
  str3 = str3.split('');
  
  let res = '';
  str1.map(e => { // Берём буквы строки str1 и проходим по ним циклом
    if(str2.includes(e)) { // Если в str2 есть такая буква
      res += e.toUpperCase(); // То записсываем её в переменную, в верхнем регистре
      test.innerHTML += `<span style="color: red;">${e.toUpperCase()}</span>`; // # ДЛЯ ТЕСТА
    } else if(str3.includes(e)) { // Если в str2 не нашлось, то ищем в str3
      res += e; // и так же записываем в переменную
      test.innerHTML += `<span style="color: blue;">${e}</span>`; // # ДЛЯ ТЕСТА
    } else { // А если их нет и там, и там, то тогда они просто пропадут.
      test.innerHTML += `<s style="color: grey;">${e}</s>`; // # ДЛЯ ТЕСТА
    }
  });
  test.innerHTML += '<br>'; // # ДЛЯ ТЕСТА
  return res;
}

console.log(revString('stopgame', 'sam', 'topge'));
console.log(revString('stopam', 'sam', 'top'));
console.log(revString('непонятно', 'мятно', 'ватно'));
```

```css
s {text-decoration-color: #000;}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: господи, теперь я считаю себя тупым, просто потому, что писал тоже самое только пытался сделать не инклудом, а индексом